# PostgreSQL: Dynamic SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, grafana, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to fabricate a dynamic SQL query that will yield a table, which name is stored inside a string.
Firstly, I need to split the string, because there are multiple tables. I only need the second one. That's why I used the SPLIT_PART function. It gives me the right name, query is build just fine, but it doesn't return anything.
How do I fix this please? Or is there some other approach to this kind of problem?

Important note is, that I'm doing this in Grafana. I cannot really change the format of the input string. Also, I need to preserve the names of the columns inside the table.

My code:

```
SET
  search_path TO emex_gen2_7371;

DO $$
DECLARE
  tbl_name text;
  dyn_query text;

BEGIN

  SELECT SPLIT_PART('${comparison_1:doublequote}', ',', 2) into tbl_name;

  dyn_query := 'SELECT * FROM ' || tbl_name;
  
  EXECUTE dyn_query;

END $$;
```

I tried to look for the solution online, but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous procedure block [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) doesn't return anything by design. You can return through side-effects, for example save the ouput of your dyn_query into a table that you can read after the procedure is done: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RnarL4GW)

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS emex_gen2_7371;
SET search_path TO emex_gen2_7371;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 as select 1 as id;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 as select 2 as id;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table3 as select 3 as id;

DO $anon_proc$
DECLARE
  tbl_name text;
  dyn_query text;
BEGIN
  SELECT SPLIT_PART('table1,table2,table3', ',', 2) INTO tbl_name;
  dyn_query := format('CREATE TABLE emex_gen2_7371.my_anon_proc_output 
                       AS SELECT * FROM %1$I ;', tbl_name);
  EXECUTE dyn_query;
END $anon_proc$;

SELECT * FROM emex_gen2_7371.my_anon_proc_output;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |

Normally, if you want a routine to return something directly to the caller, you're supposed to make it a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). Problem is, if your output structure is dynamic (each call can produce different number of columns of different types and names), you might be better off saving it to a table and reading from it later.